Мнгновенное прерывание цикла в Python
Я провел некоторые эксперименты и выяснил что цикл while завершается при неистинности условия только после полного окончания выполнения блока внутри цикла. Как можно сделать чтобы такой цикл прерывался в независимости от этапа выполнения вложенного кода, и если
это невозможно то какие можно использовать альтернативы, либо во время "эксперимента" я что то упустил и неправильно понял и на самом деле это работает не так?
from threading import Thread
import time

global quit
quit = []

def go():
    time.sleep(25)
    quit.append(5)
    print('go')

def func():
    for i in range(100000000):
        pass


Thread(target=go).start()

while 5 not in quit:
    for i in range(10000000000):
        if i%100000==0:
            print(f'{i} {quit}')
print(quit)

это примерный набросок кода на котором я и ставил эти наблюдения
в данном случае после написания в терминалие "go" (то есть добавления числа 5 в список quit, из-за чего по сути цикл должен прерваться) итерация внутри цикла продолжается. К слову отдельный поток функции go тут не причем т.к. эту пятерку в список в итоге она добавляет и ее даже видно при выводе в предпоследней строке.

Добавьте пример кода в вопрос

Цикл while не будет выполнять блок внутри цикла при неистинности условия. Вероятно, Вы вычисляете внутри цикла нечто, что влияет на условие while. В этом случае, да, блок отработает до конца и проверит условие на следующей итерации. Можно поставить еще одну проверку внутри блока, аналогичную проверке в while и при неистиности применить оператор break (выход из цикла), но, скорее всего, это костыль и можно решить как-то более адекватно. Точнее можно сказать только после того, как Вы предоставите код.

Все, добавил код.

Условие цикла while только на цикл while влияет, но не на вложенный цикл for. Чтобы for прерывался, можно например добавить в него условие if 5 in quit: break

Я заметил что такое работает не только с циклами но и с остальным кодом

Остальной код вообще никак не смотрит что там в условии while написано. На это условие только сам while смотрит, причем только при входе в цикл и в конце цикла, когда нужно проверить - выполнять ли еще одну итерацию цикла или выходить.

Понял, только как все таки можно сделать чтобы определенный код заканчивал свое выполнение сразу при неистинности условия или такое невозможно?

почитайте, что такое область видимости. а как сделать то, что вы хотите вам написали четырьмя комментариями выше.

@ВанильПестов, добавляете проверку этого условия и если оно не истинно делаете выход. Как вариант, если у вас какой-то цикл бесконечный выполняется все время пока работает программа, а при выходе должен завершиться - запускаете его в отдельном потоке, при создании потока указываете параметр daemon=True, тогда поток автоматом будет завершен при завершении всех других потоков (когда программа завешится, по сути).

Прервать нить без её согласия нельзя. Внутренние структуры интерпретатора могут оказаться в несогласованном состоянии. Этой проблеме много лет, и нигде нет метода thread.terminate(). А process.terminate() есть:
import multiprocessing
import time


def f():
    for i in range(10 ** 10):
        if i % 1_000_000 == 0:
            print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    p.terminate()
    print('terminated')
    p.join()

